# How to Speed-Up slow Push with Git/TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, bitbucket, push, tortoisegit

When i used [Fling](https://www.nchsoftware.com/fling/index.html), I was used to upload changed files to my server within 2-3 seconds...

Now, I commit changes to BitBucket with TortoiseGit (and then [buddy.works](https://buddy.works/)  automatically syncs my repo to sFTP server). However, pushing 1 changed file (to my BitBucket), takes about 10 seconds. Is there any way to speed-up the process? (i.e. disable something this or that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you compare CLI speed over tortoise-git speed? It might not be convenient in your case, but just to mention it, a CLI push is tremendously faster than the same operation with tortoise.

I'm ready to admit that tortoise-git has nice features to diff files on the spot, especially during merges, get an actually readable graphic tree representation, and so on, but even if you use these features, for a simple operation a git bash window is just a click away...

For the anecdote part, where I work we have all mixes of practices. I use CLI only (not that I'm some sort of guru, on the contrary I figured I'd learn faster this way), one coworker uses exclusively tortoise-git, and another uses a mix of the two, depending on the needs. So far neither has it created any problems nor has it impeded communication in any way.

(then again, your specific context could make CLI use unavailable or inconvenient, tell us more)